# Не загружается картинка спрайта в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, спрайт

Код:

```
import pygame
import os
width = 800
height = 650
fps = 60

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
gamepapka = os.path.dirname(__file__)
kartinka = os.path.join(gamepapka,'img')
sprite_foto = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(kartinka,'pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg')).convert()
class sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = sprite_foto
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (width / 2,height / 2)
pygame.init()
ekran = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Game')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
selfsprite = pygame.sprite.Group()
imgg = sprite()
selfsprite.add(imgg)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for x in pygame.event.get():
        if x.type == pygame.quit():
            run = False
selfsprite.update()
selfsprite.draw(ekran)
pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

Ошибка:

```
sprite_foto = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(kartinka,'pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg')).convert()
FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory.
```

Если указать полный путь:
`r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg'`:

```
    File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Cat&Milk\Cat&Milk.py", line 11, in <module>
            sprite_foto = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(kartinka,r'C:\Users\lolo\Desktop\pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg')).convert()
        pygame.error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized
```

**Необходимо исправить ошибку и запустить pygame с спрайтом с картинкой**

Comment: oшибка в пути (если py файл лежит на рабочем столе) перед именем файла должна быть папка img, но и это не все  'C:\Users\user\Desktop\img\pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

Тут рабочий пример, помимо этого я заметил на сложных проектах в pygame что количество глобальных переменных влияет на производительность - лучше их помещать в соответсвующие классы.

```
import os
import pygame

pygame.init()

size = width, height = 800, 650
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
fps = 60

gamepapka = os.path.dirname(__file__)
kartinka = os.path.join(gamepapka,'img')

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
sprite_foto = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(kartinka,'pusheen-cat-pixel-art-image-vector-graphics-pusheen-drawings.jpg')).convert()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class sprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, photo):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = photo
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (width / 2,height / 2)

my_sprite = sprite(sprite_foto)

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
        break
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    screen.blit(my_sprite.image, my_sprite.rect)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```